# What is links relative to when used in srcdoc attribute in a iframe element?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

If I have a html file `A.html`, that has js code loaded from an external js file `A.js` in another folder. The js code creates an iframe with html in its `srcdoc` attribute

```
<iframe srcdoc='<script src="file.js"></script>'></iframe>
```

Then inserts that iframe in the dom. The question is where is the file.js relative to?

Thanks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

a.html

```
<iframe srcdoc='<script src="file.js"></script>'></iframe>
```

file.js

```
document.write('fnj');
```

[image]
It will basically give output of that particular js file in iframe

Comment: but where does file.js need to exist on the server? Does it have to be in the same folder as A.html?

Comment: you can give path to that src of the js which you want to use

Comment: for example : you html path is NewFolder/test/a.html   and your js path is NewFolder/file.js

Comment: i know I can give a path, but I want to know, by default where is it relative to?

Comment: then src will be:  '../file.js'   .. will take you out from the folder, by applying '../' you will be accessing content inside the NewFolder

Comment: if src = "file.js" then fie.js should be with that perticular html file

Comment: i mean file.js should be in the same folder as html file